# K2 onclick add rating 5 onclick

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla-k2

As the title say i want to make an extra field with an onclick function that adds 5 stars of rating in K2

Like this:

```
<a class="add-rating">Click me</button>

<script>
  var add = ('.add-rating');

  add.click(function() {
  +1 vote in the rating ;
  });
</script>
```

something like that i have no idea how to do  this i have been trying to make it work for a couple of weeks now and i will be very greatful if you guys could hep me !

Comment: Ratings will have to be stored in the database so they are remembered. For this, you will need to develop a plugin that add this functionality. Why don't you use a pre made plugin from the Joomla Extensions Directory?

Comment: I need the rating to make a toplist from the most clicked items,
And its in category view the link out from the website will be with the click function to it , and every time someone clicks on a link out from the site to se that item in the webshop we want stats to make a toplist for the customers. sorry for my bad english ! if you know a plugin in the JED it would be awsome to use that. @Lodder

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension with K2

extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/k2-extensions/19253